# SQLite DB and NSLibraryDirectory folder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5

I am saving my SQLite DB on my iPhone app in the NSLibraryDirectory folder. 
Now I need to push an update to the app , Just wanted to know the update will cause to replace the existing Database ?? Which would make my users all the progress of the app.

Comment: Do you have any code to post that does any initialization of the DB or anything that would cause a wipe? Are you using straight up sqlite and not core data?

Comment: I am using straight up sqlite. I am storing the DB on NSLibraryDirectory folder. I want know weather updating my app will replace the existing database with a new one ? AS I know NSDocuments folder will remain same between udpates. Is the same behaviour applies to the NSLibrary folder as well ?

Comment: The easiest way to test is to install on your phone via the simulator, make changes, then install a new copy over it via simulator.

Comment: Please share if you found the answer. I'm curious :)